# Relation between left derivations, right derivations and number of parse trees?

Tags: context-free, parsers

I saw this question on a test-prep site

> Given a CFG and a string, what is the relation between the number of leftmost derivations, the number of rightmost derivations and the number of parse trees?

and the accepted answer was this

> For any unambiguous grammar,

> LMD and RMD is same and we have only 1 parse tree. Therefore LMD = RMD = #Parse tree

> For ambiguous grammar,

> LMD = RMD <= #Parse tree

I understand the result for unambiguous grammars. For an ambiguous grammar and a string, I don't understand how the number of parse trees is greater than the number of derivations. A distinct parse tree will always have a distinct left derivation, which will imply a distinct right derivation isn't it?

A distinct parse tree $\Rightarrow$ Distinct right derivation $\Leftrightarrow$ Distinct left derivation.

Hence, wouldn't #RD=#LD=#Parse Trees for unambiguous grammars too.

Comment: Yes, this is a mistake. A leftmost derivation (or a rightmost derivation) is a canonical way to derive a word according to a parse tree.